# How to check whether GUID is zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, guid

What is the most concise yet readable way to check whether a GUID is zero? I have come up with the following code:

```
GUID myGuid /* = ... */ ;
GUID zeroGuid;
memset(&zeroGuid, 0, sizeof(zeroGuid));
if (!IsEqualGUID(myGuid, zeroGuid))
{
    // ... do something if GUID is not zero ...
}
```

But I think above code is too clumsy. Of course, I could define my own IsZeroGUID() function, but I guess that there already is built-in function in C++.

Is there a better way?

Comment: IsEqualGUID is not a "built-in function" of C++. It's part of the Win32 COM API.

Comment: @Axel Gneiting: `GUID` definition is not part of C++ either - it is in Windows SDK together with `IsEqualGUID()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Compare with `GUID_NULL`:

```
if( myGuid != GUID_NULL ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the cleanest solution. Even though `GUID_NULL` and `operator!=(REFGUID, REFGUID)` are defined in the SDK header files, it is a pity that they are not documented in the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`myGUID == zeroGUID` should do the trick.